# How to update latest record using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have table attendance

```
    sno         |   OutTime
----------------+--------------
    1           |    2016-01-01
    2           |
```

How I get latest sno for passing my update query?
What is the select statement for getting latest sno?

```
update attendance set outtime=now() where sno=---?
```

Comment: Something like `select max(sno) from attendance`. I am not very good in postgre, check documentation for right sintax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query:

```
update attendance
set outtime = now()
where sno = (select max(sno) from attendance);
```